# DRM content with MM7 protocol Submit Request

Tags: java, soap, mm7, saaj

I am creating a SOAP request to MMSC for posting DRM content (.dm file which is a 3gp video).

I am using Saaj API for the same. 
The MMSC to which I sending the request to says that they need the SOAP request in the following format as its a 3gpp standards for submitting the SOAP request for a VASP.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="XXX123456789PQR"; type=text/xml; start="<dna_003_mm7type>"
Content-Length: 14636
SOAPAction: ""

--XXX123456789PQR
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-ID: <dna_003_mm7type>

<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop/">
 <env:Header>
<mm7:TransactionID xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-0"
 env:mustUnderstand="1">dna_vasp_003</mm7:TransactionID>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
 <SubmitReq xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-3">
  <MM7Version>5.6.0</MM7Version>
  <SenderIdentification>
   <VASPID>2222</VASPID>
   <VASID>company</VASID>
  </SenderIdentification>
  <Recipients>
   <To>
    <Number>xxxxxxx</Number>
   </To>
  </Recipients>
  <ServiceCode>gold-sp33-im42</ServiceCode>
  <LinkedID>123456789</LinkedID>
  <MessageClass>Informational</MessageClass>
  <TimeStamp>2004-03-12T9:30:47-05:00</TimeStamp>
  <EarliestDeliveryTime>2004-03-12T09:30:47-05:00</EarliestDeliveryTime>
  <ExpiryDate>8400</ExpiryDate>
  <DeliveryReport>true</DeliveryReport>
  <ReadReply>true</ReadReply>
  <ReplyCharging>true</ReplyCharging>
  <replyDeadline>2004-05-12T9:30:47-05:00</replyDeadline>
  <replyChargingSize>9198</replyChargingSize>
  <Priority>Normal</Priority>
  <Subject>News for today</Subject>
  <ChargedParty>Sender</ChargedParty>
  <DistributionIndicator>true</DistributionIndicator>
  <Content href="cid:XYSFGA-135" allowAdaptations="true"/>
        </SubmitReq>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
--XXX123456789PQR
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="company"

--company
Content-Type: application/vnd.oma.drm.message; boundary="drm-boundary-409B8BD9"
Content-ID: base64_4.dm
Content-Location: base64_4.dm

--drm-boundary-409B8BD9
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=scen2.jpg
Content-Location: scen2.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--drm-boundary-409B8BD9--
--company--

--XXX123456789PQR--
```

Can anyone pls suggest me what I need to do to send different MIME type for a single file attachment. Are there any Java API available to create such requests??? As using SAAJ, I am only to attach one MIME-TYPE for single attachment.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Cannot add multiple attachments to SOAP request? Or cannot change mime-type for single attachment? Some illustrative code samples would also be appreciated.

Comment: let me put in more clearly. I have 3gp DRM protected file that has to be sent as an attachment to me partner. They say that to a single attachment there are expecting the different content headers like - (1)--company
Content-Type: application/vnd.oma.drm.message; boundary="drm-boundary-409B8BD9"
Content-ID: base64_4.dm
Content-Location: base64_4.dm and (2)--drm-boundary-409B8BD9
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=scen2.jpg
Content-Location: scen2.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Comment: This did not help much. Can you write: 1) what is the end result you are trying to achieve (HTTP request sample); 2) what is your current solution (HTTP request sample + Java code) and what is wrong with it (in term of HTTP request sample). Finally, it would be helpful, if you would add this to your original question instead of comments - that way you have more formatting options available.

Comment: I am able to submit the request.But my partner says the SOAP message is not proper and he needs the SOAP message in the following format as stated in my 1st post. And which I am not able to achieve with SAAJ API.

Comment: You current question outlines the end-result you are trying to achieve, but does not give enough information about the part that you are struggling with. I suggest you to: 1) find out and add here the actual request being sent (either from your partner or by snooping it yourself, e.g. with wireshark); 2) add code samples to illustrate your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to deliver .dm encoded files over MMS? DM is used for Separate-Delivery protection method and a handset will need to purchase and download rights in another transaction before content can be viewed. I'm pretty sure that a lot of handset doesn't even support it.

I had more success with MMS and DRM by simply using Forward-Lock protection. To use it, just wrap around a forward lock container in MM7 request.

To generate all this in java see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21663398/3290316