# How to send MMS with MM7 using Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mms, mms-gateway, mm7

Please let me know is there any way to send MMS using MM7 protocol in Java?

If there is a free API to generate the appropriate SOAP message please let me know it too. I'm in a dead end situation and I really need a way to do this. Your wise suggestions are also welcome.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The MMS Soap should look like this: [3GPP MM7 SOAP Spesicifation](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2).

Here is how I'm doing it:

You will need activation.jar, saaj-api.jar, activation.jar, and saaj-impl.jar (and any other dependent jar files).

Here is how you can start out.

```
package com.pixelandtag.mms.soap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.xml.soap.AttachmentPart;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.Name;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBodyElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeaderElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;



public class MMSGen {

private static final String TxId = "";
private static final String MM7_VERSION = "";
private static final String VASPID = "";
private static final String VASID = "";
private static final String SHORTCODE = "";
private static final String SERVICE_CODE = "";
private static final String LINKED_ID = "";
private static final String MMSCMPMMS0000 = "";
private static final String EARLIEST_DELIVERY_TIME = "2006-11-09T13:01:04+03:00";
private static final String EXPIRY_DATE = "2007-11-10T13:01:04+03:00";
private static final String DELIVERY_REPORT = "false";
private static final String READ_REPLY = "false";
private static final String SUBJECT = "";
private static final String DISTRIBUTION_INDICATION = "false";


/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    
    try {
        
        //SOAP Message created
        MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(); 
        
        //Now accessing the elements of the soap message
        SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart(); 
        
        //Get the envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope(); 
        
        
        //You can now use the getHeader and getBody methods 
        //of envelope to retrieve its empty SOAPHeader and SOAPBody objects.
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
        
        //Other ways of getting the body and header
        //header = message.getSOAPHeader();
        //body = message.getSOAPBody();
        
        
        //Deleting a node.
        //header.detachNode(); 
        SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
         
        //================CONSTRUCTING HEADER
        Name headerName = soapFactory.createName("TransactionID",
                  "mm7", "http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2");
         
        SOAPHeaderElement headerElement = header.addHeaderElement(headerName); 
        headerElement.setTextContent("TID."+TxId);
        headerElement.setMustUnderstand(true);
        //===============HEADER DONE======================
        
        
        
        
        //===============CONSTRUCTING BODY==============
        Name bodyName = soapFactory.createName("SubmitReq");
        SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
        Name attributeName = envelope.createName("xmlsn");//change name to proper to xmls, though it does not print out
        bodyElement.addAttribute(attributeName, "http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2");
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("MM7Version");
        SOAPElement MM7Version =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        MM7Version.setTextContent(MM7_VERSION);
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("SenderIdentification");
        SOAPElement SenderIdentification =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("SenderAddress");
        SOAPElement senderAddress =  SenderIdentification.addChildElement(bodyName);
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("ShortCode");
        SOAPElement shortCode =  senderAddress.addChildElement(bodyName);
        shortCode.setTextContent(SHORTCODE);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("Recipients");
        SOAPElement recipients =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
       
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("To");
        SOAPElement to =  recipients.addChildElement(bodyName);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("Number");
        SOAPElement number =  to.addChildElement(bodyName);
        number.setTextContent(MMSCMPMMS0000);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("VASPID");
        SOAPElement vaspID =  SenderIdentification.addChildElement(bodyName);
        vaspID.setTextContent(VASPID);
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("VASID");
        SOAPElement vasID =  SenderIdentification.addChildElement(bodyName);
        vasID.setTextContent(VASID);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("ServiceCode");
        SOAPElement serviceCode =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        serviceCode.setTextContent(SERVICE_CODE);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("LinkedID");
        SOAPElement linkedID =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        linkedID.setTextContent(LINKED_ID);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("MessageClass");
        SOAPElement messageClass =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        messageClass.setTextContent(MessageClass.Personal.toString());
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("EarliestDeliveryTime");
        SOAPElement earliestDeliveryTime =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        earliestDeliveryTime.setTextContent(EARLIEST_DELIVERY_TIME);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("ExpiryDate");
        SOAPElement expiryDate =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        expiryDate.setTextContent(EXPIRY_DATE);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("DeliveryReport");
        SOAPElement deliveryReport =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        deliveryReport.setTextContent(DELIVERY_REPORT);
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("ReadReply");
        SOAPElement readReply =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        readReply.setTextContent(READ_REPLY);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("Priority");
        SOAPElement priority =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        priority.setTextContent(Priority.Normal.toString());
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("Subject");
        SOAPElement subject =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        subject.setTextContent(SUBJECT);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("ChargedParty");
        SOAPElement chargedParty =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        chargedParty.setTextContent(ChargedParty.Recipient.toString());
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("DistributionIndicator");
        SOAPElement distributionIndicator =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        distributionIndicator.setTextContent(DISTRIBUTION_INDICATION);
        
        
        bodyName = soapFactory.createName("Content");
        SOAPElement content =  bodyElement.addChildElement(bodyName);
        
        attributeName = envelope.createName("href");//change name to proper to xmls, though it does not print out
        SOAPElement attr = content.addAttribute(attributeName, "cid:A0");
        
        attributeName = envelope.createName("allowAdaptations");//change name to proper to xmls, though it does not print out
        attr = content.addAttribute(attributeName, "false");
        //=====================BODY DONE================
        
        
        
        //=================create attachment===========
        
       // AttachmentPart attachment = message.createAttachmentPart(); 
        
        
        //Simple attach
       /* String stringContent = "Update address for Sunny Skies " + 
        "Inc., to 10 Upbeat Street, Pleasant Grove, CA 95439";

      attachment.setContent(stringContent, "application/smil");
      attachment.setContentId("update_address");

      message.addAttachmentPart(attachment); */
        
        
        URL url = new URL("http://www.petermak.nl/webalbum_peter_mak_aannemersbedrijf011002.jpg");
        DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(url);
        AttachmentPart attachment1 = 
          message.createAttachmentPart(dataHandler);
       // attachment.setContent(stringContent, "application/smil");
        attachment1.setContentId("attached_image");

        message.addAttachmentPart(attachment1); 
        
        
        URL url2 = new URL("file:///C:\\Users\\Timo\\Desktop\\MMS Pis\\pic_test.jpg");
        dataHandler = new DataHandler(url2);
        AttachmentPart attachment2 = message.createAttachmentPart(
                    dataHandler);
        attachment2.setContentId("attached_image2");

        message.addAttachmentPart(attachment2);
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
       
        
       java.net.URL endpoint = new URL("http://theendpoint.");
      
      
      
        
       
         
       SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = 
              SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance(); 
        
        SOAPConnection connection = 
              soapConnectionFactory.createConnection(); 
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint); 
         
         
         connection.close();
        
        
    
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}


}
```

Comment: Please let me know which service provider, you have used.

Answer (score 5):

Over the years I had to connect to various MMSCs using MM7 protocol. SAAJ approach is a valid one, but from time to time you have to manually craft MM7 messages as MMSCs tend to be picky about exact MIME formatting, SOAP, even binary vs. base64 encoding.

At my company we've developed a library that manages MM7 SOAP and attachments at a low level depending only on JDOM. It works regardless of actual MM7 protocol version/schema. Recently we've decided to open source it, you can get it here https://github.com/vnesek/instantcom-mm7

Example:

```
    SubmitReq sr = new SubmitReq();
    sr.setVaspId("xxx_vaspid");
    sr.setVasId("xxx_vasid");
    sr.setSubject("Nice weather");
    sr.setMessageClass(MessageClass.INFORMATIONAL);
    sr.setServiceCode("7007");
    sr.addRecipient(new Address("+385910000001", RecipientType.TO));

    // Add text content
    TextContent text = new TextContent("We got a real nice weather today.");
    text.setContentId("text");
    sr.setContent(text);

    // Initialize MM7 client to MMSC
    MMSC mmsc = new BasicMMSC(url);

    // Send a message
    SubmitRsp submitRsp = mmsc.submit(sr);
    System.out.println(submitRsp);
```